# Set of Riesz homomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, vector-lattices

In a text I am using it states the following:
"The set of all Riesz homomorphisms between two Riesz spaces does not ordinarily have a simple structure of its own. Consider for example, the set of Riesz homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which is not closed under ordinary addition."

Can anyone see how it is clear that the set of Riesz homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is not closed under ordinary addition? Is there a clear example which shows that this set is not closed under addition?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the supremum in $\mathbb R^2$ is taken pointwise, i.e., $(x,y)\vee (x',y')=(x\vee x',y\vee y')$, the projections $p_1$ and $p_2$ onto the first and second variable are Riesz homomorphisms.

However, their sum is not: You can easily find $(x,y),(x',y')\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $(x+y)\vee (x'+y')\neq (x\vee x')+(y\vee y')$.